# Api calls to MVC urls with Virtual Directory fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I am using IIS Express with a virtual directory for my MVC 3 project.

From the browser, the website works well - `http://localhost:8080/VirtualDirectory/Home` etc.

But I also have designed an API that I call from another desktop tool.

The problem is that it calls to `http://localhost:8080/VirtualDirectory/Api/Action` fails. It times out.

The same thing worked with Cassini web server without the VirtualDirectory from both browser and desktop tool.

Please help. What should I do? Any changes to web.config or MapRoute?

Comment: Getting a 404 or an exception?

Comment: Actually it waits almost a minute (long time) and then goes to the correct action with null data (POST data etc). On the client front there is operation timed out error.

Comment: I think I found the answer to your issue, have a look at my last comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using web api, you should replace 'Action' for 'Controller':

```
http://localhost:8080/VirtualDirectory/Api/CONTROLLER
```

Comment: But "Api" is already a controller (ApiController). Will your solution still work?

Comment: You need a different route for web api like this: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Note that a route for web api uses routes.MapHttpRoute() while a mvc route uses route.MapRoute()

Comment: I am using MVC3 where MapHttpRoute doesn't seem to be available. I am not in a position to upgrade to MVC4.

Comment: goths is not using Web Api, he just made a controller that is called Api.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide more details: Could you use Fiddler to see what's going on when issuing the POST to `http://localhost:8080/VirtualDirectory/Api/Action` with your desktop client?

Which version of IIS Express are you using?

If you made any changes to the default route could you paste them in the question?

Are the browser, IIS and the desktop client on the same machine?

Comment: Something strange is happening. I tried the url using Fiddler and there was no error. Then I tried my desktop client without changing anything & it started working. I closed Fiddler and then even my desktop client started failing. The request hangs for a long time and then goes to the right action with invalid POST data. But all works well when Fiddler is running side-by-side.

Comment: I think we found your issue then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030218/httpwebreqest-works-with-fiddler-on-otherwise-timeout more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827030/httpwebrequest-times-out-on-second-call

Comment: Yes, this most likely is the problem. But since I have written the client in VC++ MFC, I am finding it hard to achieve the same using the CHttpConnection & CHttpFile classes. I have been working on it since yesterday. Appreciate your perseverance to help me.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question in this case (your issue is not related to IIS / ASP.NET MVC).