# .NET HttpClient hangs after several requests (unless Fiddler is active)

Tags: httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I am using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to post a sequence of requests from a console application to a REST API and to deserialize the JSON responses into strongly-typed objects. My implementation is like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
    var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyClass>().Result;
}
```

However, I am experiencing a problem very similar to one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030218), whereby everything works fine when the requests are routed via Fiddler, but it hangs after the 4th or 5th request when Fiddler is disabled.

If the cause of the problem is the same, I assume I need to do something more with `HttpClient` to get it to fully release its resources after each request but I am unable to find any code samples that show how to do this.

Hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not disposing of the `HttpResponseMessage` object. This can leave open streams with the server, and after some quota of streams with an individual server is filled, no more requests will be sent.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
    using(var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result)
    {    
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyClass>().Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew - that was a life-saver. In fact, I have seen this problem before when using HttpWebRequest and the solution was the same, but it wasn't immediately obvious how to do this with the HttpClient code pattern. Thanks again.

Comment: There is something else going on here.  The only stream here is the NetworkStream that is passed into the StreamContent object that is assigned to the Content property of the response message.  When HttpClient is used like this, the response body is automatically buffered and any non-seekable stream will automatically be disposed when it gets buffered.  There is no need to dispose a HttpResponseMessage that is retrieved by HttpClient using HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead.