# Best practice to avoid multiple disposals with the `using` keyword in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, idisposable, using-statement

When a variable is IDisposable, we have the `using` keyword to manage the disposal. But what if we return the value in a method, should we have `using` twice?

```
StringContent stringToStringContent(string str)
{
    using (StringContent content = new StringContent(str))
    {
        return content;
    }
}

void logStringContent()
{
    using (StringContent content = stringToStringContent("test"))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(content.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

In this example above, I only have 1 `new` but I have 2 `using` for the same thing. So I feel it's unbalanced. Is it better to:

a) keep both `using`, and the language/compiler knows its job to avoid double-disposal?

b) keep only `using` with `new` together, and no need in other cases?:

```
void logStringContent()
{
    StringContent content = stringToStringContent("test");
    Debug.WriteLine(content.ToString());
    return;
}
```

c) keep only `using` when you don't return, and no need when you return?:

```
StringContent stringToStringContent(string str)
{
    return new StringContent(str);
}
```

The only thing I can feel is that b) isn't the correct answer, because it wouldn't work for issues like the one described here: [.NET HttpClient hangs after several requests (unless Fiddler is active)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095545/net-httpclient-hangs-after-several-requests-unless-fiddler-is-active)

Comment: Almost every implementation of `.Dispose` that I've seen implements it using the pattern of calling a `Dispose(bool disposing)` overload where `disposing` is only true the first time.  Thus in most implementations calling `.Dispose` multiple times is harmless.

Comment: In your first code example, why aren't you just doing `return new StringContent(str);`?  For that matter, you could just `using StringContent content = new StringContent(str)` and you haven't lost anything.  C is the correct answer.

Comment: @KirkWoll Whether the object is safe to dispose more than once isn't the issue here; no matter whether it's safe, the OP shouldn't be immediately disposing (and presumably rendering unusable) a new object, then returning it to a caller which expects to use it. And the goal of the "Disposing pattern" is for an object to distinguish being disposed by `IDisposable.Dispose` (`disposing`) from being disposed by the finaliser (`!disposing`). It doesn't have any bearing on whether `Dispose` has already been called - `disposing` should be true for *every* call to `Dispose` in a correct implementation.

Comment: @shambulator, of course you are correct; but I thought given the question title some emphasis on that reality (that multiple disposes are generally harmless) was merited.

Answer (score 6):

I think `c` is the right answer here - you're returning (a reference to) an object from the method - it makes no sense to have already disposed of that object before you return it. For example, `File.OpenRead` wouldn't dispose of the stream that it returns, would it?

It would be a good idea to indicate in the method documentation that the caller takes responsibility for disposing of the object though. Likewise, some methods *accept* a disposable type and state that the caller then shouldn't dispose of the object themselves. In both case there's effectively a transfer of responsibility for disposing of the object properly.

Comment: +1. In most cases good name is enough documentation - I'd name the method so it is more clear it acts as factory - i.e. `CreateStringContent`. Returning disposed object is not something I can find any use for.

Answer (score 0):

Having methods that return `IDisposable` objects is not an uncommon pattern, but preventing resource leaks when exceptions occur can be difficult.  An alternative approach is to have a method which will produce a new `IDisposable` accept an `out` or (if the method is unsealed and virtual) `ref` parameter, and store a reference to the new object in that.  The caller would then be expected to `Dispose` the thing in question, whether the method that produced it returned normally or threw an exception.

Otherwise, if you want your method's return value to be a new `IDisposable`, and if any code will execute between the time your method acquires a resource and the time it returns, you should guard your code with something like:

```
DisposableThing thingToDispose = null;
try
{
    thingToDispose = new DisposableThing(whatever);
    // Now do stuff that might throw.
    // Once you know you're going to return successfully...
    DisposableThing thingToReturn = thingToDispose;
    thingToDispose = null;
    return thingToReturn;
}
finally
{
    if (thingToDispose != null)
      thingToDispose.Dispose();
}
```

Note that this code doesn't "catch" any exceptions, but if the function exits other than via the proper designated path the newly-constructed object will get disposed.  Note that if this function throws an exception without disposing of the newly-constructed object, any resources acquired by that object will leak, since the caller won't be able to dispose it.