# .NET HttpClient.PostAsync() slow after 3 requests

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am using the .NET 4.5 HttpClient class to make a POST request to a server a number of times. The first 3 calls run quickly, but the fourth time a call to `await client.PostAsync(...)` is made, it hangs for several seconds before returning the expected response.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    // Prepare query
    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    queryBuilder.Append("?arg=value");

    // Send query
    using (var result = await client.PostAsync(BaseUrl + queryBuilder.ToString(),
        new StreamContent(streamData)))
    {
        Stream stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        return new MyResult(stream);
    }
}
```

The server code is shown below:

```
HttpListener listener;

void Run()
{
    listener.Start();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
     {
        while (listener.IsListening)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
            {
                var context = c as HttpListenerContext;
                try
                {
                    // Handle request
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Always close the stream
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                }
            }, listener.GetContext());
        }
    });
}
```

Inserting a debug statement at `// Handle request` shows that the server code doesn't seem to receive the request as soon as it is sent.

I have already investigated whether it could be a problem with the client not closing the response, meaning that the number of connections the ServicePoint provider allows could be reached. However, I have tried increasing `ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints` but this has no effect at all.

I also found this similar question:

[.NET HttpClient hangs after several requests (unless Fiddler is active)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095545/net-httpclient-hangs-after-several-requests-unless-fiddler-is-active)

I don't believe this is the problem with my code - even changing my code to exactly what is given there didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting that to 10 but it doesn't have any effect

Comment: Use a different server (google.com). Is the problem still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there were too many `Task` instances scheduled to run.

Changing some of the `Task.Factory.StartNew` calls in my program for tasks which ran for a long time to use the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option fixed this. It appears that the task scheduler was waiting for other tasks to finish before it scheduled the request to the server.

Comment: If you exhaust the thread-pool limits your app has **serious** issues. Fix that instead of hiding the problem with LongRunning.

Comment: Part of my app is listening for connections on various ports, so I have a thread dedicated to listening on each of the ports. It seems ok to change the tasks for these threads to be long running because they are necessary?

Comment: You could do that. That would be a stable app since the load is off of the pool. But since you are using async IO with await, just use that for accepting.

Comment: No, I was using other Tasks for things other than the HttpClient here